# changeCanvasOpacity gets changed after Transition

Tags: android, canvas, android-studio, transition, android-transitions

My problem occurs a few seconds after a transition is complete. The Log says "changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=true", which puts a black screen on my mapview. When i return to Activity A opaque gets changed to false again. So my question is, why does the transition change the CanvasOpacity and how do i prevent it in the first place.

Its exactly like this [Parent activity becomes invisible on exit transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386493/parent-activity-becomes-invisible-on-exit-transition)
Did someone found a solution?

/edit: in my code the Opacity appears on top of the mapview, unlike here [SurfaceView in Android Wear (API 21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232939/surfaceview-in-android-wear-api-21) im not using a surfaceview, which prevents me from using setZOrderOnTop(true) in the constructor.
Is there any clever way to achieve something similiar on a mapview(linear/frame layout) not using  surfaceview

Comment: i still havent found a solution, but apparently if your using a surfaceview it is solvable https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82985

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having exactly the same problem: I have a view with a couple of fragments, and one of the fragments contains a MapView. If I use activity transition to open that activity the map was totally black, it only got back to normal if I went to another activity and then back to that one. What I did was replace the MapView for a MapFragment (a fragment within a fragment) and then it was working perfectly. The only thing is that you can only place fragments within other fragments in Android 4.2+, but if you have your MapView directly in your activity layout, try to replace it with a MapFragment and I guess you won't have any problem. I hope it works for you.

Cheers.